# Delphi local variables memory management (stream compression with ZLib)

Tags: delphi, memory-management, stream, local-variables

I've written this very simple function:

```
function CompressStream(inpStream: TBytesStream;
                        nCmpLevel: TZCompressionLevel = zcFastest): TBytesStream;
var
  aCmpData: TBytes;
begin
  ZCompress(inpStream.Bytes, aCmpData, nCmpLevel);
  Result := TBytesStream.Create(aCmpData);
end;
```

Is this correct? I have a doubt about the memory persistence of the data in the local array variable `aCmpData`.

If we cut the row `Result := TBytesStream.Create(aCmpData)` we have `aCmpData` going out of scope when the function ends, so its associated memory is freed.

The constructor for `TBytesStream` takes a `TBytes` so I pass it my local array, this should be a "by reference" operation.

What about my data when the function ends and `aCmpData` goes out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TBytes` type is a dynamic array of bytes, declared as:

```
TBytes = TArray<Byte>;
```

Such dynamic arrays are managed by the compiler, just like `string` variables. There is no need to release the variable explicitly, its lifetime is managed by the compiler. When there are no remaining references to the array it will be destroyed.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the question: my concern is not on the need to release `aCmpData` memory manually, but if the compiler will release it automatically even if I've passed it to `TBytesStream.Create()`. Anyway your answer seems to clarify that passing an array to a function will actually increase its reference count, so after the implicit `dec(aCmpData.RefCount)`, this is still >0 so my data will not be freed, right?

Comment: Just for completeness, there should be a `aCmpData.RefCount := 1` before the `try..finally` block ;)

Comment: Dynamic arrays are not COW, only strings are.

Comment: @LURD you're right. This isn't relevant for my specific case, but the answer should be corrected.

Comment: It is possible to incorporate COW on dynamic arrays if you can ensure that every change is preceded with `SetLength(myDynArray,Length(myDynArray));`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why did you delete a whole part of the answer? What on earth are you thinking?

Comment: Much of it was wrong, and what wasn't wrong was off-topic

Comment: @LURD There is no COW when you modify an item (as happens when you modify a char within a string), but there is COW when you resize the array. If you change an array size, it will make a private unique copy, following the COW pattern. Your comment about SetLength() is IMHO misleading, and the [correct way of making an array unique is to use Copy()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays).

Comment: @Bozzy NO, the RefCount is set to 1 when the array is allocated, i.e. within the ZCompress() sub-function, when calling System.DynArraySetLength, not before the try..finally block.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was an illustration of what happens behind the scene, by inlining some RTL calls emitted by the compiler, but not wrong, sorry. You [are really trolling and exasperating me](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.ns1yx8wdm). If you want, create your own answer, but don't mess with other's!

Comment: This site is a wiki. Anyone can edit any post. Once you post here, it's not your post. It belongs to the site. I'm not trolling you, I am trying to explain how this site works. Your posts don't seem to fit in always. If you don't want to be part of SO, that's obviously your choice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not anyone can. You can. I can also. Since we have enough points. But SO is not a wiki with unique page (like the Delphi documentation). It expects multiple answers, then use ranking to let most acceptable answers first. Your edition sounded like a [clear breaking of the edit policy/spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). You totally changed my answer by deleting most of its content. And didn't even state what you thought was wrong in its original content - and I still doubt it was wrong.

Comment: What was wrong was your assertion that dynamic arrays are COW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are wrong, my dear. ;) They have COW abilities, as I wrote in my above comment. Not like a Delphi string's COW, when you write an item. But COW is a pattern wider than Delphi string. When you resize one dynamic array instance, there will be a new single copy created, ready to write on it. Copy-On-Write. So they are NOT pure reference types.

Comment: COW means that a copy is performed implicitly whenever you write. Stating that if you explicitly copy before writing means that they are COW is interpreting COW in a completely unique fashion.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, *Following a call to SetLength, S is guaranteed to reference a unique string or array -- that is, a string or array with a reference count of one.* My previous comment was just to explain that dynamic arrays in general are not 100% COW, without using `SetLength` (or Copy() if you like).

Comment: We will always find exceptions. If you use a PChar transtyping over a string, then modify one item in the PChar, COW detection won't work. I mean `PChar(aString)[10]` for instance - whereas `PChar(@aString[1])[10]` will make a private copy.There is no such thing as completely unique / 100% COW. You need to know how the compiler works. What I wrote is that dynamic arrays feature COW, and they actually do. I didn't write "like string".

Comment: Dynamic arrays do not have any COW features, by any recognised definition of COW

Comment: You start becoming funny, as a troll. I suspect you are speaking about [this COW](https://dirtycow.ninja/), not [this COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

Comment: Nope, I'm referring to the second one. That's what strings do and what dyn arrays don't.

Comment: What a shame to read all these comments! The answer ArnaudBouchez proposed was quite clear to me, although it may not be perfect (COW vs MAN). His example showing the compiler emitted code was illuminating, while your edit @DavidHeffernan still insists on the "There is no need to release the variable explicitly", which I already know and is exactly WHY I asked this question. Again: I was not asking if I have to release the memory by myself, on the contrary, my concern was if the compiler would release memory when the variable goes out of scope WHILE I'm still using its contents elsewhere.